# Harvesting data with rvest retrieves no value from data-widget

Tags: r, rvest, data-harvest

I'm trying to harvest data using `rvest` (also tried using `XML` and `selectr`) but I am having difficulties with the following problem:

In my browser's web inspector the html looks like

```
<span data-widget="turboBinary_tradologic1_rate" class="widgetPlaceholder widgetRate rate-down">1226.45</span>
```

(Note: `rate-down`and `1226.45` are updated periodically.) I want to harvest the `1226.45` but when I run my code (below) it says there is no information stored there. Does this have something to do with 
the fact that its a widget? Any suggestions on how to proceed would be appreciated.

```
library(rvest);library(selectr);library(XML)
zoom.turbo.url <- "https://www.zoomtrader.com/trade-now?game=turbo"
zoom.turbo <- read_html(zoom.turbo.url)
# Navigate to node
zoom.turbo <- zoom.turbo %>% html_nodes("span") %>% `[[`(90)

# No value
as.character(zoom.turbo)
html_text(zoom.turbo)  

# Using XML and Selectr
doc <- htmlParse(zoom.turbo, asText = TRUE)
xmlValue(querySelector(doc, 'span'))
```

Comment: I guess that when it is updated periodically, it will not have an initial value when the html is harvested with rvest. You could try working with `RSelenium` package. It is a bit more complex to setup, but basically you use a browser you can command from within your R script.

Comment: Great, I will give it a shot. Thanks

Comment: @Wietze314 After some playing around I got `RSelenium` to work and am able to harvest the information I need (albeit slowly but fast enough for my purposed). If you want to post your comment as an answer, ill give you the reward.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For websites that are difficult to scrape, for example where the content is dynamic, you can use `RSelenium`. With this package and a browser docker, you are able to navigate websites with R commands.

I have used this method to scrape a website that had a dynamic login script, that I could not get to work with other methods.